# Node colliding with other node when it shouldn't

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, collision-detection, skphysicsbody, skaction

I have a node that spawns every couple seconds and move across the screen from the right side. I want the score to increase every time the player come in contact with this node but I want the player to go straight through it instead of being blocked by it. Right now the score goes up when the player hits it and it spawns and moves properly but it stops the player from moving past it. I have tried multiple solutions such as making the collisionBitmask of the score line equal to 0 but I'm still new to objective-c so I don't know a solution so any help would be greatly appreciated.

The following is all the code above "@implementation"

```
@interface GameScene ()

@property (nonatomic) SKSpriteNode *clouds;
@property (nonatomic) SKSpriteNode *player;
@property (nonatomic) SKTexture *pipeTexture1;
@property (nonatomic) SKTexture *pipeTexture2;
@property (nonatomic) SKAction *_moveAndRemovePipes;
@property (nonatomic) SKNode *moving;
@property (nonatomic) SKLabelNode *scoreLabelNode;
@property (nonatomic) int score;

@end

static const uint32_t playerCategory     = 1;       
static const uint32_t pipeCategory       = 2;       
static const uint32_t bottomEdgeCategory = 4;
static const uint32_t edgeCategory       = 8;
static const uint32_t scoreCategory      =16;
```

Heres the code that has to do with the score line. Please note that my code to add the score label is it my initWithSize method.

```
-(void) addScore:(CGSize) size{

// Initialize label and create a label which holds the score
//    _score = 0;
//    _scoreLabelNode = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"MarkerFelt-Wide"];
//    _scoreLabelNode.position = CGPointMake( CGRectGetMidX( self.frame ), 3 * self.frame.size.height / 4 );
//    _scoreLabelNode.zPosition = 100;
//    _scoreLabelNode.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _score];

//add score line
SKNode *contactNode = [SKNode node];
contactNode.position = CGPointMake( self.frame.size.width + _pipeTexture1.size.width - 10   , CGRectGetMidY( self.frame ) );
contactNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake( 5, self.frame.size.height )];
contactNode.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
contactNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = scoreCategory;
//    contactNode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory;

//move score line
CGFloat distanceToMove = self.frame.size.width + 2.4 * _pipeTexture1.size.width;
SKAction *movePipes = [SKAction moveByX:-distanceToMove y:0 duration:0.01 * distanceToMove];
SKAction *removePipes = [SKAction removeFromParent];
SKAction *moveNode = [SKAction sequence:@[movePipes, removePipes]];

[contactNode runAction:moveNode];
[_moving addChild:contactNode];
//    [self addChild:_scoreLabelNode];
}
```

The following is my initWithSize method and I've taken out some of the unimportant code.

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

    //change gravity
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake( 0.0, -5 );

    //add physics to world
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

    //add moving node to keep track of animations
    _moving = [SKNode node];
    [self addChild:_moving];

    // Initialize label and create a label which holds the score
    _score = 0;
    _scoreLabelNode = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"MarkerFelt-Wide"];
    _scoreLabelNode.position = CGPointMake( CGRectGetMidX( self.frame ), 3 * self.frame.size.height / 4 );
    _scoreLabelNode.zPosition = 100;
    _scoreLabelNode.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _score];
    [self addChild:_scoreLabelNode];

    SKAction* spawnScore = [SKAction performSelector:@selector(addScore:) onTarget:self];
    SKAction* delayScore = [SKAction waitForDuration:2.0];
    SKAction* spawnThenDelayScore = [SKAction sequence:@[delayScore,spawnScore]];
    SKAction* spawnThenDelayForeverScore = [SKAction repeatActionForever:spawnThenDelayScore];
    [self runAction:spawnThenDelayForeverScore];

    [self addScore:size];    
}
return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to detect contact between two SKNodes and don't want them to collide, set their `contactTestBitMask` to the the `categoryBitMask` of the other, and `collissionBitMask` to zero.

For Example, In your case

```
player.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = playerCategory
player.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = scoreCategory | otherCategories
player.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0 // This can be categories other than score categories

scoreNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = scoreCategory
scoreNode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory | otherCategories
scoreNode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0
```